# How to make a JavaScript program so that one API call doesn't hider other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a JavaScript API, but this API doesn't let the other API get called or call itself again during the time that it runs. Specifically, this API involves sleeping for a duration of time and while this is sleeping I expect that other API calls or same API call should also happen.

I have created a sample program for the same, and it behaves analogously. Looking for your comments and suggestions, thanks.

```
'use strict';

// importing required libraries
const sleep = require("sleep");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 1234;
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// this is the function that just sleeps for 30 seconds and after that is resolves the output
// because of this function the API calls needs to wait till it is completed
const promisified = async function () {
    console.log("Promisified started")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let count = 0
        console.log("promisified hit")
        while (true) {
            console.log("Sleeping for 30 seconds. Try: ", count);
            sleep.sleep(30);
            if (count >= 1) {
                console.log("Timeout breaking");
                return resolve("Broke out");
            }
            count += 1;
        }
    })
}

// this is the function that is being called on the API hit, which internally calls promisified function
const justafunction = async function (req, res) {
    console.log("Just a function api hit");
    res.status(200).send("api hit")
    promisified()
        .then(data => {
            console.log("This then is workd...",data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error is :", err);
        });
    let x = await promisified();
    console.log("X is here...",x);
}

// this is the API that we will call
app.get("/test", justafunction);

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(" Server Successfully Started ", port);
});
```

Ideally, in python and C++  would open up a thread to do the job independently but I don't have interal working of JavaScript much. Hence, any comment in that context will be much appreciated.

Comment: or run the blocking task in another node process

Comment: @RandyCasburn - nodejs has [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) built-in now.  Web Workers are something a browser has built-in.

Comment: So, you need to learn how to program in a single-threaded event driven environment like nodejs.  You do NOT sleep the main thread in nodejs - ever.  If you tell us what real problem you're trying to solve with the sleep, we can offer some better design ideas.  There are always ways to design this that work in nodejs, but sleeping the main thread is never one of them.  Also, a `while(true)` loop is almost never used in nodejs programming either for the same reason as they block the event loop (there is one exception if it's in an async function and you use `await` inside the loop).

Comment: @jfriend00 - thanks.

Comment: @jfriend00 The issue I have at hand is that I have a 3rd party API which takes time to succeed, so I need to query and check the status of the call to the API. The way I thought was to use the while loop and check every 30 seconds for the status outcome and when I get errored or succeeded I break out. 

Only after this status can I then proceed to the other step.

Comment: In nodejs, if you're just waiting for an operation to finish, you would use the callback or promise associated with that action to tell you when it's done.  If you're polling some external state with an http request or something like that, then you would schedule a future polling check with a timer.  If that doesn't find it's done yet, you schedule the next check with another timer and so on... You don't loop for things like this.  Using timers allows other things to run and frees the thread to do other work while waiting for the timer.

Comment: FYI, your questions here will ALWAYS get better answers if you show the real code and the real problem, not pseudo code or theoretical code.  That way, we can target answers specifically to what you're really trying to do and can offer you solutions you didn't even know to ask about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded: the event loop manager thread executes JavaScript code and hence can do nothing else until the JavaScript code being executed runs to completion (i.e. returns to the event loop).

No sleep function exists in JavaScript. To run synchronously this function call

```
sleep.sleep();
```

must record the time on entry and enter a polling loop that reads the time until the system clock has advanced sufficiently to return. Until such time the function continues to loop without returning to the event loop and blocks the thread.

An alternative using `async` and `await` could be:

```js
function sleep( msec) {
    return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, msec));
}

// calling example

async function test() {
  console.log("sleep for 3000 msec");
  await sleep(3000);
  console.log("sleep expired");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", test);
```

```html
Sleep for 3 seconds: <button type = "button">ok</button>
```

Note the version of sleep returning a promise must be called from an `async` function in JavaScript after an `await` operator, or have have fulfillment handler added to it using a `then` handler. The key to it working with `await`is that the `await` operator returns to the event loop until its operand promise becomes settled, allowing other code to be executed in the main thread.